# gzip command block returns "Too many levels of symbolic links"

Tags: gzip, bioinformatics, bioconductor, nextflow

Trying to perform a fairly simple gzip command across my fastq files, but a strange error returns.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.gzip = "sequences/sequences_split/sequences_trimmed/trimmed*fastq"

workflow {

gzip_ch = Channel.fromPath(params.gzip)
GZIP(gzip_ch)
GZIP.out.view()

}

process GZIP {
input:
    path read
output:
    stdout
script:
    """
    gzip ${read}
    """
}
```

Error:

```
Command error:
  gzip: trimmed_SRR19573319_R2.fastq: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Tried running a loop in the script instead or run gzip on individual files which works, but would rather use the nextflow syntax.

Comment: Can you try using `gzip -f ${read}` to make it follow the symbolic link?

Comment: Yes, the command seems to pass, but the files themselves remain as fastq and not fastq.gz

Answer (score 0):

Michael!

I can't reproduce your issue. I created the folders in my current directory like you described and created four files in it, as you can see below:

```
➜  ~ tree sequences/
sequences/
└── sequences_split
    └── sequences_trimmed
        ├── trimmed_a_fastq
        ├── trimmed_b_fastq
        └── trimmed_c_fastq
```

Then I copy-pasted your Nextflow script file (the only change I did was to use `gzip -f ${read}` instead of without the `-f` option. Then everything worked fine. The reason you need `-f` is because Nextflow has every task contained to a subfolder within `work`. This means your input files are symbolically linked and `gunzip` will complain they're not regular files (happened here, macOS Ventura) or something like that (It may depend on OS? Not sure). The `-f` solves for this issue.

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 22.10.1
Launching `ex2.nf` [golden_goldstine] DSL2 - revision: 70559e4bcb
executor >  local (3)
[ad/447348] process > GZIP (1) [100%] 3 of 3 ✔
➜  ~ tree work
work
├── 0c
│   └── ded66d5f2e56cfa38d85d9c86e4e87
│       └── trimmed_a_fastq.gz
├── 67
│   └── 949c28cce5ed578e9baae7be2d8cb7
│       └── trimmed_c_fastq.gz
└── ad
    └── 44734845950f28f658226852ca4200
        └── trimmed_b_fastq.gz
```

They're gzip compressed files (even though they may look just like text files, depending on the demo content). I decided to reply with an answer because it allows me to use markdown to show you how I did it. Feel free to comment this answer if you want to discuss this topic.

Comment: You should be able to reproduce the error with something like `touch foo; ln -s foo bar; gzip bar`. Best to avoid using `-f` if possible. Bad things can happen if you use too much force..

Answer (score 0):

By default, Nextflow will try to stage process [input files](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#input-type-file) using symbolic links. The problem is that `gzip` actually ignores symbolic links. From the GZIP(1) man page:

> The **gzip** command will only attempt to compress regular files.  In particular, it will ignore symbolic links.

If the objective is to create a reproducible workflow, it's usually best to avoid modifying the workflow inputs directly anyway. Either use the [`stageInMode`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#stageinmode) directive to change how the input files are staged in. For example:

```
process GZIP {

    stageInMode 'copy'

    input:
    path fastq

    output:
    path "${fastq}.gz"

    """
    gzip "${fastq}"
    """
}
```

Or, preferably, just modify the command to redirect stdout to a file:

```
process GZIP {

    input:
    path fastq

    output:
    path "${fastq}.gz"

    """
    gzip -c "${fastq}" > "${fastq}.gz"
    """
}
```